# My splash screen on my app is now a dark screen after upgrading to android 12

Tags: xamarin, android-12

Splash screen is black after upgrading my phone to android 12. The app is written in Xamarin. Not sure what to do to fix this. I am using a splash_screen.xml is there a better way?

Comment: There is a new Splash Screen API in Android 12, you might want to look into: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen

Comment: @Cheesebaron Doesn't really say how to implement it in Xamarin.

Comment: @Vladimir what I ended up doing is leaving the splash screen alone. I don't think that Microsoft has implemented all the api's if you leave it alone it will use the Icon in the splash which goes along with alot of the other apps in the store